# Как получить доступ на запись к переменной из другого модуля webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть два модуля. Для сборки webpack экспортирую переменную из одного модуля в другой.
Значение переменной можно прочитать в другом модуле, однако менять это значение нельзя.
Хотелось бы понять, почему так и как с этим бороться?

```
import {ttt} from './common.js';

console.log('Что я вижу из другого модуля:', ttt);

ttt = 'фффффффф';
console.log('А теперь:', ttt);
```

```
let ttt = 'мы должны видеть это в другом модуле';
export {ttt}
```

Вот что видно в консоли:

Что я вижу из другого модуля: мы должны видеть это в другом модуле TicTacToe.js:4

Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property "ttt"
 TicTacToe.js:6
 index.js:525
 index.js:528

Comment: Может попробовать в лоб `let rrr = ttt; rrr = 'парарам'` ?

Comment: А потом экспортировать rrr обратно? Ситуация такова, что несколько переменных являлись общими для нескольких файлов. Все нормально работало, пока я не захотел собрать модули с помощью webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По крайней мере один рабочий способ я нашел. Не скажу, впрочем, что он кажется удобным. Для каждой переменной требуется создавать и экспортировать функции-геттеры и сеттеры.

```
let ttt = 'мы должны видеть это в другом модуле';

const getttt = () => ttt;
const setttt = (val) => (ttt = val);

export {getttt, setttt}
```

```
import {getttt, setttt} from './common.js';

console.log('Что я вижу из другого модуля:', getttt());

setttt('фффффффф');
console.log('А теперь:', getttt());
```

В результате содержимое переменной действительно меняется:

Что я вижу из другого модуля: мы должны видеть это в другом модуле TicTacToe.js:4

А теперь: фффффффф TicTacToe.js:7